# Listdir sorted by extension PYTHON

Tags: python, listdir

I need to print out the listdir of current directory, but sorted by file type. Something like this:

```
ASCII text:
 text
bzip2 compressed data, block size = 900k:
 strace_4.5.20.orig.tar.bz2
gzip compressed data, extra field, from Unix:
 openssh_5.8p1.orig.tar.gz
gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified:
 eglibc_2.11.2.orig.tar.gz
 strace_4.5.20-2.debian.tar.gz
gzip compressed data, from Unix, max compression:
 openssh_5.8p1-2.debian.tar.gz
PDF document, version 1.0:
 attestazione.pdf
PDF document, version 1.2:
 risPP.9dic03.pdf
 risparz.7nov03.pdf
```

All this in python. On linux there's `file` command. How about in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `os` module, get the extension of a file using  `os.path.splitext` and then use `list.sort`.

```
import os
files = os.listdir(path)
def func(x):
   return os.path.splitext(x)[::-1]
files.sort(key = func)
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> lis = ['file1.zip', 'file2.zip', 'inotify.c', 'cmpsource.c', 'myfile.h']
>>> def func(x):
       return os.path.splitext(x)[::-1]
>>> lis.sort(key = func)
>>> lis
['cmpsource.c', 'inotify.c', 'myfile.h', 'file1.zip', 'file2.zip']
```

Comment: It seems ok but when i try it on a real list of files, i get a non ordered list by extension.

Comment: @AntonioFalcone add that real list of files in question body along with expected output.

Comment: the problem is that 'path' is only the current directory path (/home in this case) and not the real path of every file.

Comment: @AntonioFalcone `os.listdir` returns a list of all files from a particular directory, path to each file is not required.

Comment: @AntonioFalcone If you want to sort by name as well then replace this line : `return os.path.splitext(x)[-1]` with `return os.path.splitext(x)[::]`

Comment: The sample list of file is: file1.zip file2.zip inotify.c cmpsource.c myfile.h

Output should be: C PRG cmpsource.c C PRG inotify.c H lib myfile.h Zip File file1.zip Zip File file2.zip

Comment: @AntonioFalcone what's `C PRG`?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. The right sorting method was:

```
files = os.listdir(folder)

files.sort(key=lambda f: os.path.splitext(f)[1])
```

Comment: This is **exactly** what I was doing, btw this will not sort by file name.

i.e `file2.txt` may come before `file1.txt`.